# How do I modify an array, remove spaces from it, and store it in a new array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

For example, I want to store elements of this string in an array, [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9].

```cpp
    string s = "[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]";
    string news[100];
    int leng1 = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < leng1; i++)
    {
        int v = test.find(";");
        if (v == -1)
        {
            limo[i] = s.substr(0, leng1);
            break;
        }

        limo[i] = s.substr(0, v);
        test = test.substr(v + 1, v + leng1);
    }
    string s = "[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]";
```

I want to store numbers without spaces and semicolons.

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  If you can make your problem as simple as possible while still creating the failure, it will help us isolate the issues that will make your code work correctly.  By providing a main() function, it saves time for the person trying to duplicate your error and help you.

Comment: The code you have provided will not compile.  limo is not defined.  Not sure if this is a string or if it is supposed to be an integer array.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a string `"[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]"` and produce an integer array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` from it?

Comment: Was `limo` supposed to be `news`?

Comment: It's too bad you haven't responded with what has been asked, because the way to do this using modern C++ requires no loops, no `substr` calls, and would be 5 lines of code or less.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes

Comment: @AbdelHalimAbdelAziz ok, so what is stopping you? You know how to search a string for delimiters, and how to extract substrings. All you are missing is a string-to-int conversion, and you can do that many different ways: `std::atoi()`, `std::stoi()`, `std::istringstream` with `operator>>`, etc

Comment: @RemyLebeau  thnx

Comment: Clarified wording.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to store those numbers in an `int` array, there are ways to accomplish this without having to write `for` loops, calling `substr`, etc.

To do this, one way is to first replace the unwanted characters with spaces.  Once that's done, then it is a matter of using the facilities available in C++ that allows to parse and store items when given a string as input.

The following uses [std::replace_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) to replace the characters and [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse the string.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s="[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]";
    // store items here
    std::vector<int> news;

    // replace unwanted characters with a space
    std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char ch){return ch == ']' || ch == '[' || ch == ';';}, ' ');

    // parse space delimited string into the vector
    std::istringstream strm(s);
    int data;
    while (strm >> data)
       news.push_back(data);

    // output results
    for (auto& v : news)
      std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b97c6c7b39f5cd6d)